# Can't paste all text in wpf textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, paste

I have a simple window and textbox, when i try to paste this code to the textbox

```
[Code]General           : sample.avi
Format            : AVI
Length            : 380 MiB for 16mn 57s 320ms

Video #0          : DivX 5 at 2994 Kbps
Aspect            : 1024 x 576 () at 25.000 fps

Audio #0          : MPEG-1 Audio layer 3 at 128 Kbps
Infos             : 2 channels, 48.0 KHz   [/code]
```

It stops after

```
[Code]General           : sample.avi
```

Why?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to allow your TextBox to accept newlines:

```
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

Comment: I'm ashamed, not new to .net but starting with wpf, thx works.

Answer (score 8):

Is the textbox set to accept new lines? Set these properties to the textbox:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap" //Wrap text within the text box
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" //If you want scroll bars
AcceptsReturn="True" //This does the magic.
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to allow multi-line by:

TextWrapping="Wrap"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
AcceptsReturn="True"

Answer (score 2):

I probably spent a good hour or two on this. Ugh.  I finally noticed that the paste was stopping at a paragraph (i.e., newline).  This insight allowed me to Google to something useful (this answer).  Need keywords C# Paste Truncated Incomplete Newline or somesuch.  I used C# years ago, and didn't have this issue.  Thanks